# Save save_kable() to png with white background instead of default gray

Tags: r, kableextra

I just need to change the background color of the whole table to white. A reproducible example

```
kable(head(iris)) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = FALSE, htmltable_class = 'lightable-classic-2') %>%
  add_header_above(c("Measurements" = 4L, " " = 1L)) %>% 
  kable_paper() %>%
  save_kable(file = 'tableX.png')
```

[image]

What've found/tried:

- `add_header_above()` has a background argument but that only affects the header.
- `save_kable()` has the `bs_theme` argument but I can't find what the options are.
- some functions have the `extra_css` argument but can't find a function that affects the whole table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some examples of `bs_theme` at [bootswatch.com](https://bootswatch.com/)
For my example I used `flatly`.

```
library(kableExtra)


kable(head(iris)) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = FALSE, htmltable_class = 'lightable-classic-2') %>%
  add_header_above(c("Measurements" = 4L, " " = 1L)) %>% 
  kable_paper() %>%
  save_kable(file = 'tableX.png', bs_theme = "flatly")
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I should have looked in the source code. Now I see if I type unavailable theme I get `'arg' should be one of "default", "cerulean", "journal", "flatly", "darkly", "readable", "spacelab", "united", "cosmo", "lumen", "paper", "sandstone", "simplex", "yeti"`